# How to achieve this navigation menu in android

Tags: android, android-layout

I need to achieve a navigation menu such as this:

[image: Navigation menu]

I don't want to use Navigation drawer since I am already using it for other purposes.

Let me explain a little bit the situation:

I have a navigation drawer that shows a listview with some options. When user clicks on an option, navigation drawer disappear and in may content view should show some buttons with the look & feel as the image above.

When a button is pressed, a new view (corresponding to button selection) should slide in from the right.

How can I achieve this? I have not found a good resource for this.

Thanks
Jaime

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2013/11/android-sliding-menu-using-navigation-drawer/

Comment: http://sunil-android.blogspot.in/2013/09/slide-menu-navigation-drawer-in-android.html

Comment: https://github.com/johnkil/SideNavigation

Comment: https://github.com/codepath/android_guides/wiki/Fragment-Navigation-Drawer

Comment: This sounds extremely non-Android. You should stick to the platform's navigation guidelines or your users will be confused.

Comment: Not only this is not an Android approach to navigation but also it will confuse your users a lot - I would recommend to stick to "classic" Android navigation hierarchy

Comment: https://github.com/ChiragSavsani/AndroidMaterialDesign and https://github.com/ChiragSavsani/CustomViews

Comment: Why is this confusing? I think to have 2 navigation drawers will be confusing. Remember I told that I am already using a navigation drawer. How can I have another navigation drawer so that the app will not be confusing? If you refer to the image I have posted, there are buttons in the content view. That is almost exactly what  want to achieve, with the difference that I need the view that appear when I click a button, should slide in (only to give a cute animation). Maybe I did not explain the problem clearly.

Comment: I want to achieve something visually like this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12342969/split-action-bar-creating-menu-after-clicking-an-item. Look at the My Maps option

Comment: better, I need to get exactly what Gmail app does.... that is, a list of the messages (in my case they are texts retrieved from an XML file).. when click on a text, a new view wth the content is shown. How can implement this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it finally by using a ListView.

This is the code,and I can assure it is not confusing, and in fact, this is done in every android app:

```
public void DrawAreas() {
    final ListView areaView = (ListView) _activity.findViewById(R.id.area_list);

    ArrayAdapter<TdcArea> areas = new ArrayAdapter<TdcArea>(_activity.getApplicationContext(),
            android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
            _system.getAreas()) {
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            View view = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);
            TextView text = (TextView) view.findViewById(android.R.id.text1);
            text.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
            Drawable icon = ContextCompat.getDrawable(_activity.getApplicationContext(), R.drawable.chevron_red);
            text.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(null, null, icon, null);
            return view;
        }
    };
    areaView.setAdapter(areas);
    areaView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            TdcArea area = (TdcArea) areaView.getItemAtPosition(position);
            Intent intent = new Intent(_activity.getApplicationContext(), FormActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("AREA", area);
            _activity.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```